# GitHub Actions runner cannot access ports.ubuntu.com

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, github

I'm building containers from GitHub Actions. I'm using Ubuntu Jammy (latest LTS, 22.04). Since few hours, the GitHub Actions runners cannot any more access to the domain hosting the Ubuntu packages for non AMD64 arch, `ports.ubuntu.com`.

How do you advise getting around this problem?

Note for `ports.ubuntu.com` maintainers: The IP ranges of GitHub Actions runners [are available by API](https://api.github.com/meta).

**Reproduction:**

1. Create a GitHub Actions pipeline
2. Add a step for build a container
3. Build your container from Ubuntu Jammy based-image
4. Execute an `apt-get install` command during the build

**Short log:**

```
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/s/shadow/uidmap_4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-26ubuntu3.1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
...
```

**Raw logs:**

```
> [linux/arm64 base 3/5] RUN --mount=target=/var/lib/apt/lists,type=cache,sharing=locked --mount=target=/var/cache,type=cache,sharing=locked     apt-get update -q     && apt-get upgrade -y -q     && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends         build-essential         ca-certificates         cargo         curl         dbus-user-session         git         git-lfs         gnupg         gzip         iptables         iputils-ping         jq         libffi-dev         libssl-dev         lsb-release         make         pkg-config         python3-dev=3.10.*         python3-pip         python3=3.10.*         software-properties-common         sudo         tar         uidmap         unzip         wget         zip         zsh         zstd:
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/s/shadow/uidmap_4.8.1-2ubuntu2.1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_6.0-26ubuntu3.1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/z/zip/zip_3.0-12build2_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/z/zsh/zsh_5.8.1-1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libz/libzstd/zstd_1.4.8%2bdfsg-3build1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/r/rustc/libstd-rust-dev_1.65.0%2bdfsg0ubuntu1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/r/rustc/rustc_1.65.0%2bdfsg0ubuntu1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/universe/c/cargo/cargo_0.66.0%2bds0ubuntu0.libgit2-0ubuntu0.22.04_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi-dev_3.4.2-4_arm64.deb  Unable to connect to ports.ubuntu.com:80: [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
#14 575.8 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```